# Roots of a polynomial with irrational coefficients

Tags: polynomials, roots

I know about algebraic numbers and transcendental numbers.
How the roots of a polynomial with irrational coefficients are classified.
Are they transcendental?

Comment: They are not necessarily transcendental: Take any polynomial with rational coefficients and multiply its coefficients by $\sqrt{2}$. This is a polynomial with irrational coefficients, which has the same roots as the original.

Comment: @J.J. What happens if they are different? (e.g. rt2, rt3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients are all algebraic, and a monic polynomial whose roots are all algebraic has algebraic coefficients.

So a monic polynomial with some transcendental coefficient must have at least one transcendental root (and vice versa), but it can also have algebraic roots (for example, $0$ is a non transcendental root of $X^2- \pi X = 0$).

Comment: If you change $\sqrt{2}$ to $\pi$ in J.J.'s comment you need not have a transcendental root even if the coefficients are transcendental.

Comment: right, I forgot to keep the monic condition.